# Still need of asp.net MVC when jQuery is available?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I read several reasons to switch to asp.net MVC, but none of them are, imho, worthing the cost to go back to square one and throwing away all you have learnt about webforms: how to deal with postbacks, viewstate, the page life cycle and... all the rest.

The main issue MVC wants to solve - the postbacks - can already be solved with webforms using jQuery and webmethods.

Or am I missing the point, and my (little, to tell the truth) knowledge about asp.net webforms is quickly becoming obsolete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of WebForms is to make it easy to build interactive websites with little knowledge of web technologies (HTTP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc). But this comes with a cost, you have to study WebForms. I spent 2 years studying and working with WebForms, then realized it's much  easier and better to understand the web technologies.

A server-side framework like ASP.NET MVC makes it very easy to handle requests, a client-side framework like jQuery makes it very easy to manipulate HTML and make AJAX requests. These things were hard to do when WebForms appeared in the scene, but today are very easy.

I know you are scared to give up your skills, but you should be focusing on learning the core web technologies.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree about postbacks being the main issue MVC looks to solve.  Although that certainly is a benefit, MVC is mostly about separation of concerns.  It's a great way to logically separate and organize your business logic, models, HTML templates, etc.  And if you really need/want to use webforms as well, MVC lets you mix those in.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC is not about avoiding postbacks, it's about separation of concerns, unit testability, and working closer with the stateless nature of the web and raw HTML rather than the abstractions of ASP.NET web forms.

Your knowledge of ASP.NET web forms is not becoming obsolete. ASP.NET MVC has very little marketshare currently, and migrating ASP.NET web forms applications to ASP.NET MVC is not a trivial task. The two frameworks will coexist just fine for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1):

Web Forms is and will be for a while, an alternative for web application development.  MVC is also an alternative for web application development.  Each has their strengths, and different uses.  As with any tool, use the appropriate one for the job.

I like MVC because it was designed with testability and plugability in mind.  Web Forms is a bit too rigid for my liking and doesn't lend itself easily to testing.

I also prefer to have complete control over the HTML, and whilst .NET 4 introduced a few changes that makes this better, I still don't like server controls writing potentially dodgy markup.

WebForms was an abstraction layer of HTTP and HTML designed to allow people to get web apps up and running quickly, often from a non-web background such as VB6.

MVC goes back to basics, and doesn't pretend HTTP and HTML doesn't exist, but instead leverages them, and gives you as the developer more control over how they're used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using a jQuery + webmethods approach, MVC development should be fairly easy to learn.

You don't have to throw away everything you learned about webforms.  Many of the same principles for constructing excellent code still apply.